# python multiprocess with logger cannot run on Windows system

Tags: python

I have a python script with multiprocess and logger. It shows

```
raise pickle.PicklingError('logger cannot be pickled')
```

_pickle.PicklingError: logger cannot be pickled

However, the same script can run on Linux system.